# Rapidminer: Advantages of a database?

Tags: database, rapidminer

my question is, is it of any advantage to read data from a database ( like SQLServer, mongoDB, ...) into Rapidminer? instead like, for an excel table?
is it faster? or easier to read the data?
or is the only advantage that you have a database where you can store your data and not an advantage (e.g. for speed) for Rapidminer?

I wanted to either use sqlServer Express (2014 or 2016) or some open source database... its a dataset of now about 5000 records from one table, but there are at most 3 tables at the end, and the records are growing steadily over time...
can someone recommend me a database for it (maybe better open source?)

I want to use the 3 tables to make analysis of all 3 of them together in RapidMIner....

Comment: There shouldn't be any significant speed advantage because both excel and a database store everything, for the most part, as text. I think the only reason the feature is added is to make it easier for you if your data is already in a database. My favorite open source database is MySQL. I recommend running it on top of a minimal installation of Debian to get the best overall performance and stability.

Comment: Databases let you issue SQL so it's easy to filter or join tables together taking advantage of the processing power where the data is stored. Of course you can retrieve everything into RapidMiner and do everything locally but this might be inefficient if you don't want most of the data.

Comment: ok, but can I import and join different tables in rapidminer, too ? e.g I have 2 tables and some key column, and I want to join the 2 tables with the same key...?